# match.arg function for list argument

Tags: r, arguments, match

My question is simple.

```
x=list(type="call")

FUN <- function(x=list(type=c("call","put")))
{
  x$type=match.arg(x$type)
}
```

This returns an error:

```
> FUN(x)
Error in match.arg(x$type) : 'arg' should be one of “”
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's possible; from `?match.arg` the default function argument is used to match the input, but here your default is not a simple character vector.

Comment: until this gets reopened, here's one ugly workaround, `FUN = function(x=list(type=c("call","put"))){match.arg(x$type, formals(FUN)[['x']][['type']]) } ; FUN(x=list(type='call'))`

Comment: @Will this is a real R question

Comment: @baptiste it would help to notice that "does not work" usually is NARQ.  If you feel that you know why it doesn't work, it would help to [edit] and add that info.  I've reopened so you can add your workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
FUN <- function(x=list(type=c("call","put")))
{
  x$type=match.arg(x$type, c('call', 'put'))
}


> print(FUN())
[1] "call"
> print(FUN(x))
[1] "call"
> print(FUN(list(type="put")))
[1] "put"
```

Comment: Thanks. Its just what I wanted!

Comment: until now i was using pmatch("med", c("mean", "median", "mode")). But your last suggestion is the best Ive seen.